# Why we should use CMD for creating a new C# project?

Tags: c#, command-line, console-application

I am new to C#. I read a tutorial about C# that said to use CMD to create a new project.
There is the command line:

> dotnet new console -n AppName -o .

My question is why we should use this command line? We can create a new project with IDE  that is very simple.

Comment: You're not wrong.  It's probably just how the guide is written.

Comment: Because that particular tutorial is probably written totally agnostic of any IDE or similar environments, just with the means of the SDK. Because all it really takes to create a .net application is the SDK and an editor (even notepad is fine, if you know what you are doing). Of course it's much more comfortable using an IDE, but it doesn't hurt to know the principles ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point of that command is that an IDE is not required.  Visual Studio users would typically use the IDE to create projects.